# Postgresql returning repeating data on multiple join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't figure out why my output is duplicating, but I'm sure it is incorrect joins. I'm new to SQL in general, so this may be an inefficent query.

```
SELECT a.id, a.number, a.number2, b.id, b.number3, b.number4, c.id, c.score, (a.number - b.number3) as a_b_difference, (a.number2 - b.number4) as a_b_difference3 FROM file a
INNER JOIN file b on a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN file c on a.id = c.id
```

I want to subtract the two fields and combine all three files on the id. However, my result populates with repeating data.

This is a sample of what I am getting:

[image]

Comment: use distinct here

Comment: Gotcha that helps limit the duplication!

Comment: What duplication?  I see no duplicated rows.

Comment: I can provide a better answer if I know some more info.  Is `id` the primary key for the `file` table?  What are you trying to accomplish?  While Daniel's answer works, it is pretty bad advice.

Comment: id is the primary key to match on. The answer from Daniel didn't solve all the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c.id` is `a.id`, so that `join` is not needed:

```
SELECT a.id, a.number, a.number2, b.id, b.number3, b.number4, a.id, c.score,
       (a.number - b.number3) as a_b_difference,
       (a.number2 - b.number4) as a_b_difference3
FROM file a INNER JOIN
     file b 
     ON a.id = b.id;
```

As for the rest of your problem, I don't see duplication. If too many rows are being generated, perhaps you need to fix your `JOIN` conditions. You could use `SELECT DISTINCT()` if the entire row were duplicated.  If you want one row from within a group, you can use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINcT ON`.

Comment: But then I'm not getting c_score without the c.id join

Comment: This ended up working, but I needed to join on both id's, but not put them in my original select statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct a.id, a.number, a.number2, b.id, b.number3, b.number4, c.id, c.score, (a.number - b.number3) as a_b_difference, (a.number2 - b.number4) as a_b_difference3 FROM file a
INNER JOIN file b on a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN file c on a.id = c.id
```

Comment: This is pretty bad advice.  The purpose of DISTINCT is not to cover up errors from poorly written queries that duplicate rows.